# Получение информации о функциях в модуле

Tags: .net, рефлексия, f#

Заинтересовал вопрос как получить информацию о функциях которые содержит модуль. 
Хочу получить что-то вроде того, что выдает FSI.

Например для следующего модуля

```
module Test = 
    let ign _ = ()
    let getNowDateTime() = System.DateTime.Now
    let getNumbers count = [1..count]
```

FSI выводит такую информацию

```
module Test = begin
  val ign : 'a -> unit
  val getNowDateTime : unit -> System.DateTime
  val getNumbers : count:int -> int list
end
```

Пробовал достать данные через рефлексию следующим образом

```
let getInfoAboutModule (t : Type) = 

    let genericToString (t : Type) = 
        match t.GenericTypeArguments with
        | [| |] -> t.FullName
        | x -> 
            x 
            |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Name)
            |> String.concat "," 
            |> sprintf "%s<%s>" t.Name

    let getInfo (mi:MethodInfo) =
        let parameter = 
            let sb = System.Text.StringBuilder()

            for x in mi.GetParameters() do
                x.ParameterType
                |> genericToString
                |> sprintf "%s : %s ->" x.Name
                |> sb.Append
                |> ignore

            sb.ToString()
            |> fun str -> if str |> System.String.IsNullOrEmpty then "unit -> " else str

        sprintf "%s : %s %s" mi.Name parameter (genericToString mi.ReturnType) 

    t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.Static)
    |> Seq.map getInfo
```

для модуля `Test` результат будет следующим

```
ign : _arg1 :  -> System.Void
getNowDateTime : unit ->  System.DateTime
getNumbers : count : System.Int32 -> FSharpList`1<Int32>
```

[MCVE (ideone)](http://ideone.com/5HDRjC)

но, естественно, таким образом получаю названия далекие от F#-ных.

---

P.S. Добавлять какие-либо атрибуты к модулю нельзя, т.к. нужно оставить возможность извлекать данные из модулей из других сборок.

Comment: Ну как бы да, имена типов даются с точки зрения BCL, которая знать не знает о F#-овских алиасах (как впрочем и о C#-овских). Возможно, нужно строить явную таблицу соответствия.

Comment: @VladD угу, попробую еще поискать варианты - может есть какой-то обходной путь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [FSharp.Compiler.Service](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service) для анализа исходных текстов модулей. Если модуль скомпилирован и его исходных текстов нет, то сомневаюсь, что можно добиться лучшего результата, чем ваш.

На основе [этого](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/symbols.html) примера:

```
open System
open System.IO
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices

let text =
    """
module Test = 
    let ign _ = ()
    let getNowDateTime() = System.DateTime.Now
    let getNumbers count = [1..count]
    """

let checker = FSharpChecker.Create()

// из примера
let parseAndTypeCheckSingleFile input = 
    let file = "test.fsx"

    let projOptions = 
        checker.GetProjectOptionsFromScript(file, input)
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

    let parseFileResults, checkFileResults = 
        checker.ParseAndCheckFileInProject(file, 0, input, projOptions) 
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

    // Wait until type checking succeeds (or 100 attempts)
    match checkFileResults with
    | FSharpCheckFileAnswer.Succeeded(res) -> parseFileResults, res
    | res -> failwithf "Parsing did not finish... (%A)" res

// печать информации о члене модуля
let printInfo (fn:FSharpMemberOrFunctionOrValue) =
    // строка с информацией о типе
    let rec getTypeString (t:FSharpType) =
        if t.HasTypeDefinition then
            let prms = [ for x in t.GenericArguments -> (getTypeString x) ] in
                t.TypeDefinition.DisplayName +
                " " +
                String.Join(" ", prms)
        else
            t.ToString()

    printf "%s: " fn.DisplayName

    for group in fn.CurriedParameterGroups do
        for prm in group do
            match prm.Name with
                | None -> () 
                | Some name -> printf "%s:" name
            printf "%s -> " (getTypeString prm.Type)

    printf "%s\n" (getTypeString fn.ReturnParameter.Type)


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let parseFileResults, checkFileResults = 
        parseAndTypeCheckSingleFile text 

    let m = checkFileResults.PartialAssemblySignature.Entities.[0]
    let fns = m.NestedEntities.[0].MembersFunctionsAndValues

    for x in fns do printInfo x

    0
```

Результат:

```
ign: type 'a -> unit
getNowDateTime: unit  -> DateTime
getNumbers: count:int  -> list int
```

Либо можно поизучать исходники непосредственно [FSI](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs).

---

Если возникает ошибка при парсинге, нужно скопировать файлы `FSharp.Core.optdata` и `FSharp.Core.sigdata` в каталог с программой. Файлы можно найти в `%PROFRAMFILES%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.4.0.0\`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, да, модуль скомпилирован и непосредственно к исходниках доступа нет.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper тогда действительно придется строить какую-то таблицу соответствий `FSharpList``1<Int32> - list int` и т.д.

Comment: @FoggyFinder F# в реальной разработке, увы, не доводилось использовать. Я скорее просто любопытствующий.

Comment: @FoggyFinder я обновил ответ, причина в отсутствии пары файлов